# flattening an array: where does the 0 come from?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, function.prototype

This challenge is to flatten an array without defining any new functions:

```
// challenge
const arr = [1, [2]]
const flattened = arr.reduce(/*your code here, no function expressions or declarations allowed*/, [])
console.log(flattened) // expected: [1, 2]
```

My solution doesn't work, but what really bugs me is that I have no idea where the `0` is coming from:

```
// Solution 1
const arr = [1, [2]]
const flattened = arr.reduce(Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat), [])
console.log(flattened) // unexpected result: [1, 0, 1, [1], 2, 1, 1, [1]]
```

I'd expected the code to behave like the follow, which works as expected:

```
// Solution 2
const arr = [1, [2]]
const flattenReducer = (x, y) => Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)(x, y)
const flattened = arr.reduce(flattenReducer, [])
console.log(flattened) // logs the expected result: [1, 2]
```

I tested in Node, Chrome, and Firefox and got the same results.

So where is the 0 coming from and why do Solution 1 and Solution 2 produce different values for `flattened`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reduce`'s callback doesn't only have two arguments. In fact it has four: accumulator, current value, index, and the original array.

Your solution #1 is equivalent to

```
arr.reduce(function (x, y, z, a) {
    return Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)(x, y, z, a);
}, []);
```

or equivalently

```
arr.reduce(function (x, y, z, a) {
    return x.concat(y, z, a);
}, []);
```

which is wrong.

Also note that both of your solutions doesn't actually flatten arrays with more than two dimensions.

Comment: Now I see where the `0` is from, it's from the index

Answer (score 2):

`.concat()` is concatenating all of the parameters at `.reduce(function(a,b,index,array) {})`

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for reduce in this situation simply concat the const to new const or var.

```
const arr = [1, [2]];
var arrFlat = [].concat.apply([], arr);
console.log(arrFlat);
```

While wanting to understand the academic portions of this issue are valiant you'd be much better served understanding the basic usage of the base class method itself as they've been built to aid redundant use cases without the need for coupling/nesting/chaining for the most part.

Comment: He's asking why it outputs 0.

Comment: true, but that's not the code challenge: the challenge is to fill in the `/* your code here ... */`

Comment: I guess I'm more under the impression of the usefulness of the code challenge and its pragmatic usage or wording. It says no functions may be used but the users first param is a call to a superclass method.

How would mine be wrong if I'm not declaring anything in the params and am simply assigning the value to my var?

Comment: @BrianEllis this is helpful. Agreed that the code challenge is definitely not practical and that your code is better.

Comment: Regarding the edit to your answer: I don't think there's any superclassing going on here.

Comment: @mheiber Agreed there is no superclassing going on in the script he has done but in the reference to the Array object type methods which he is using there is reference to the superclass that is the array class of data objects and accessible methods of that data type. I can re-edit to remove this part though.

Comment: @BrianEllis The challenge doesn't say "no functions," it says "no [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)."

Comment: @Jordan I think we're past that. The point I was illustrating is that going down a black hole for academic purposes on the misuse of 2 methods together is far less ROI than just properly using a method as its intent and the issue isn't that the OP needs to know why the 0 is there but that he should recognize misuse of chaining native data type methods.

Comment: @Jordan also that wasn't meant to be a hostile response. It's just I see no point in semantics or taking a question as an OP's intent if an answer will lead him down the wrong road of investigation of an issue. His issue isn't not knowing why the value occurred but more it seems he doesn't know how to use the methods he implemented.